# Scrolling ul to specific li

Tags: javascript, html

I have an unordered list `#ul` with set `max-height` and `overflow-y: scroll` it houses a lot of list tags with unique id's like `#item-1`.

I am trying to figure out a way to scroll this ul element to specific li if it is selected, so far I've tried

```
let ul = document.getElementById('ul');
let li = document.getElementById('item-1') // can be item-2 etc..
ul.scrollTo(0, li.offsetTop)
```

But I get error saying that scrollTo is not a function.

Please provide vanilla js solutions only.

HTML showing what I have at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/axu8eywr/1

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Scrolling functions confused.

It's either:

- `window.scrolTo(x,y)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo
- `(element).scrollIntoView()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Both of these relate to window, Is there a way to get something like scrollIntoView to work where list element is scrolled into view of ul?